# Difference between returning a reference and a variable?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between specifying the return value/type(not sure what to say) as a reference:

```
CVector& CVector::operator= (const CVector& param)
```

and as a regular variable:

```
CVector CVector::operator= (const CVector& param)
```

Thanks!

Comment: By convention, `operator=` should return a reference to `*this` so that you can assign multiple vectors at once, much like fundamental types. `vec1 = vec2 = vec3;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thank you and thank you guys for linking the duplicate. Do not know why I did not see when I typed in my question :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think it's less about that (you can do the same when `operator=` returns a value) but I think it's more about not making an unnecessary copy every time you invoke the assignment operator.

Comment: That is to say, `a = b = c` would cause `b` to be copy-assigned from `c`, then return a copy of itself as a temporary, then `a` is copy-assigned from the temporary.  Then `a` returns itself by value, creating a second temporary.  Finally, both temporaries are destroyed.